# Prague Shopping Times and Method of Payments?

Tags: payment-cards, prague, payment

I will be visiting Prague for the first time and I am having a difficult time figuring out two things:

1. What time do shops close (if it matters, this would be on weekdays and on Saturday during the last week of November through the 1st of October).
2. Do they accept / prefer cards or cash?

Comment: I almost exclusively used cash there. Prague has exchange services all over town. Carry some cash and exchange it there. Go for the ones without fee. The rate is worste, but without the fee they are actually better most of the time. Larger restaurants etc. will usually accept credit card, though.

Comment: See my answer. Cash exchange rates are fairly lousy. Definitely for European bank cards you're better of just withdrawing from an ATM... but don't take the offered rate, let your own bank settle.

Comment: What kind of shops? The answers are going to be very different for a tiny shop on the outskirts of the city than for a large hypermarket, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.- Seems like the regular opening time is from 8:00 to 18:00 on weekdays with some exceptions in the shopping centers.

2.- Seems like both cash and cards are accepted but there's a preference on cash over cards, specially on restaurants and small shops. So seems it's more recommended to carry certain amount of cash, though seems there's a good amount of ATM so you won't have a problem.

Source (in Spanish):

https://www.lonelyplanet.es/destino-europa-republica-checa-praga-153-informacion-practica.html

Source (in English):

https://www.pragueexperience.com/information/tourist-information.asp

Answer (score 3):

I am Dutch and in Prague at the moment. Shops in the center of town are open fairly late, modern shopping center in the old town was open at 19:30 on Thursday. Probably depends on location and type of shop.

Most restaurants and shops will take any EC bank card and you get a good exchange rate on those normally. Fee is only € 0.15 with my Dutch bank and exchange rate 25.6 or 25.7 (in that range). Withdrawing from an ATM you get the same rate, only fee is € 1.25 (my bank). DO NOT accept the offer for an exchange rate from the ATM. You'll be ripped of for about 10% or worse. Credit card? Not tried except for booking the hotel on-line.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably overthinking this.

Prague is now a modern city popular in the region and with tourists.  The shops close when the merchants feel the commercial day is over.  In practice, there's no difference between Prague and any other city.  So, ~1600-1700 for retail and ~2300 for restaurants, later for bars.

Credit cards are fairly well accepted, particularly in larger establishments, but you will still need cash.  Smaller establishments will always prefer cash, but again, that's the situation everywhere.

Comment: Since there is no comment to explain, **the Downvote is wrong and misleading.**  Should be 100% ignored.